# Running the same Python code through a sort of files in the same folder

Tags: python, csv, pdf, directory

I need your help in an issue I have with a Python script I'm using. The main goal of the code is to retrieve data from CSV files in order to generate one PDF per CSV file (with the data of a list of different CSV files).

The problem I have is the code I wrote only works with the last file of the list inside Python, which my code copies the number of items the list has, instead of generating different PDFs from the different CSVs the folder has.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import glob
import datetime
from fpdf import FPDF

today = datetime.datetime.now()
files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\vhpacheco\\Desktop\\AnalisisCSV\\/*.csv')
files2 = [i + "_new" for i in files]

for j in files:
    with open(j, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

    pdf = FPDF('L','mm','Letter')
    pdf.add_page()
    page_width = pdf.w - 2 * pdf.l_margin
    
    pdf.set_font('Times','B',14.0) 
    pdf.cell(page_width, 0.0, 'Management Registry', align='C')
    pdf.ln(10)

    pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 6)
    
    col_width = page_width/14

    pdf.ln(1)

    th = pdf.font_size

    for row in reader:
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, str(row[0]), border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[1], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[2], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[3], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[4], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[5], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[6], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[7], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[8], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[9], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[10], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[11], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[12], border=1)
        pdf.cell(col_width, th, row[13], border=1)
        pdf.ln(th)

    pdf.ln(10)
    pdf.set_font('Times','',12.0) 
    pdf.cell(page_width, 0.0, 'Date and Hour: {}'.format(today), align='C')
    for cont2 in files2:        
        pdf.output('{}.pdf'.format(cont2), 'F')
```

Thanks for your advice and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Fix your indentation first. You seem to have mixed tabs and spaces. Use spaces only. Perhaps afterwards, you'll see where your mistake is.

Comment: The `with` statement creates a scope which requires an indentation, akin to a `for` loop or `def` or `class`.  When exiting that scope, `f` will be cleaned up and no longer use-able.  Right now, the scope is empty.  I'm surprised you do not have to put a `pass` there to placate the compiler.

Comment: Here's the docs for *Utilities for with-statement contexts*: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout  That shows a variety of other ways that `with` statement is used.  You can see an example with nested `with`.  The thing to glean is they all indent the same way with `with`.

Comment: Try indenting all lines under the `with`, starting with `reader = ....`